# jquery binding click event to ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some jquery that transitions slides with the mousewheel. I have added the jquery slider and have bound click events based on the ui.value vs the current slide index to transition the slides. The problem, it works fine if you do not move the slider to fast, but if you move it too fast the slide transitions current index gets out of align with the ui.value. The ui.value is correct so i'm thinking the click events in here are being skipped? site mixmastercocktails.com, click the main image for the slides to appear. Any ideas on how to make sure that the click events get called?

```
    $('#slider-vertical').slider({
    orientation: 'vertical',
    range: 'min',
    min: 1,
    max: $('#cards li').length,
    value: 1,
    step: 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        if(ui.value > current_index)
        {
            next.trigger('click');
        }
        if(ui.value < current_index)
        {
            prev.trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
```

Full js file:

```
(function($) {
var counter = 1;
var newx = 0;
var newy = 0;
var width = 475;
var nwidth = 475;
var current_index = 1;
var previous_index = 1;
var view = $('#rolodex');
var prev = $('#control-prev .prev');
var next = $('#control-next .next');        

$('#cards li').each(function() 
{
    var newz = counter+1000;

    $(this).css('z-index', newz );
    //$(this).html(newz);
    $(this).css('transform', 'translate(' + newx + 'px,' + newy + 'px)');

    $(this).css('width', nwidth +'px');
    newx = newx + 4;
    newy = newy + -2;
    nwidth = nwidth - 8;
    counter--;
});

$(document).bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) 
{
    if(deltaY >= 0) {
        next.trigger('click');          
    }
    else {
        prev.trigger('click');          
    }
});     

next.bind('click', function() {
    if($(this).attr('disabled')) return false;
    $('#cards li').filter(':nth-child(' + current_index + ')').css('transform', 'scale(1.2, 1.2)');
    $('#cards li').filter(':nth-child(' + current_index + ')').css('opacity', 0);

    newx = 0;
    newy = 0;
    nwidth = 475;

    $('#cards li').each(function(jindex) {
        if(current_index <= jindex)
        {   
            $(this).css('width', nwidth +'px');
            $(this).css('transform', 'translate(' + newx + 'px,' + newy + 'px)');               

            nwidth = nwidth - 8;
            newx = newx + 4;
            newy = newy + -2;
        }   
    });                     

    current_index ++;
    $('#slider-vertical').slider({value:current_index});        

    check_buttons();
});

prev.bind('click', function() {
    if($(this).attr('disabled')) return false;

    $('#cards li').filter(':nth-child(' + (current_index - 1) + ')').css('transform', 'scale(1, 1)');
    $('#cards li').filter(':nth-child(' + (current_index - 1) + ')').css('opacity', 1);         

    newx = 0;
    newy = 0;
    nwidth = 475;

    $('#cards li').each(function(kindex) {              
        if(current_index <= (kindex + 1))
        {   
            $(this).css('width', nwidth +'px');
            $(this).css('transform', 'translate(' + newx + 'px,' + newy + 'px)');               

            nwidth = nwidth - 8;
            newx = newx + 4;
            newy = newy + -2;               
        }   
    });

    current_index --;
    $('#slider-vertical').slider({value:current_index});

    check_buttons();    
});

function check_buttons() {
    if(current_index==1) {
        prev.attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
        prev.attr('disabled', false);
    }

    if(current_index == $('#cards li').length) {
        next.attr('disabled', true);                
    }
    else {
        next.attr('disabled', false);
    }
}

$('#rolodex-image').bind('touchstart',function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity:.70,'z-index':25}); 
    $('#cards').animate({opacity:1});
    $('#slider-vertical').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#control-prev input').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#control-next input').fadeIn('slow');
});

$('#rolodex-image').bind('click', function() {  
    $(this).animate({opacity:.70,'z-index':25}); 
    $('#cards').animate({opacity:1}); 
    $('#slider-vertical').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#control-prev input').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#control-next input').fadeIn('slow');        
}); 

$('#slider-vertical').slider({
    orientation: 'vertical',
    range: 'min',
    min: 1,
    max: $('#cards li').length,
    value: 1,
    step: 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        if(ui.value > current_index)
        {
            next.trigger('click');
        }
        if(ui.value < current_index)
        {
            prev.trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
```

})(jQuery);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slide` doesn't handle the event when you click and jump on the slider. You should use `change` instead

```
$('#slider-vertical').slider({
  orientation: 'vertical',
  range: 'min',
  min: 1,
  max: $('#cards li').length,
  value: 1,
  step: 1,
  change: function( event, ui ) {
    if(ui.value > current_index) {
      var index_change = ui.value - current_index;
      for (var i = 0; i < index_change; i++) {
        next.trigger('click');
      }
    }

    if(ui.value < current_index) {
      var index_change = current_index - ui.value;
      for (var j = 0; j < index_change; j++) {
        prev.trigger('click'); 
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I've updated the JSFiddle with the answer http://jsfiddle.net/mnQfr/13/.

Comment: current_index get incremented and decremented in prev.trigger('click');, next.trigger('click') that triggers next.bind, prev.bind functions.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle for this? I can't think of any reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: I think i understand what you mean in the question now. If you click to jump on the slider instead sliding, `current_index` and `ui.value` will be out of sync, is it correct? I've updated my answer. The question also should be updated to make it clearer.

Comment: Ryan, your solution worked, thanks, however when using change the slides would not animate until the scroll finished. not sure about the slide vs. change but updated to slide and it works perfectly.

Thanks for your help!!!!